# Connecting to SQL Server and add user results in an error

Tags: c#, sql-server

I try to write code in C# to connect to a SQL Server database so I can register an user account but I dont know why I get stuck at

```
con.Open();
```

I wrote server name correctly, I have tried with the `User ID = sa;` and `Password = ..;`, I tried without password and still nothing.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-62V61RT/SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog =ShopOnlineDB; Integrated Security=False; User ID = sa; Password= ..;");
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO User (FirstName, LastName, Email, Password) VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @Email, @Password)", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", TextBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", TextBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TextBox3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TextBox4.Text);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    Label1.Text = "Registered with success !";
}
```

Comment: Your above code *strongly* suggests you are storing plain text passwords; these is a severe and fatal flaw. **Always** salt and hash your passwords.

Comment: Please post your error msg.

Comment: `User ID = sa;` That's a terrible habit as well. And don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely just a little typo - use a **backslash** - not a forward slash - in your connection string:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-62V61RT\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog =ShopOnlineDB; Integrated Security=False; User ID = sa; Password= ..;");
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO User (FirstName, LastName, Email, Password) VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @Email, @Password)", con);

    // use the .Add() method, and explicitly define the data type 
    // (and for strings - their max length) for your parameters!
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value =  TextBox1.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox2.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = TextBox3.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = TextBox4.Text;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    Label1.Text = "Registered successfully!";
}
```

Also - it's typically **not** a good idea to use the `sa` user - preferably use either built-in Windows authentication, or create a suitable application user - but don't use the sys admin account - you're just asking for security troubles ...

You should furthermore check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

And last but not least - you should ***never ever*** store passwords in **clear text** in your database - you should **ALWAYS** (not exceptions!) hashed and salt your passwords, if you really must store them....